# Xamarin Forms Webview Local Html src doesn't load every images from URL

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I am building an application that uses the `Xamarin.Forms WebView`. Everything works fine on Android, iOS and UWP. But sometimes there is an image in the `HtmlSource` of the WebView that doesn't load. I can't find out what the problem is.

I'm trying to show this html in the `WebView`:

```
<p><img src="https://www.loi.nl/~/media/images/logos/vakgebieden/ipma.jpg" alt="Img did not load" /></p>
```

This code works fine on UWP and shows the correct image. But when running the exact same code on Android or iOS, the image doesn't show up. 
I can't find out why the `WebView` doesn't load this image on Android or iOS.

These images DID load succesful on every platform: https://www.rabobank.nl/static/generic/css/images/s14/rabobank-logo.png
http://www.learnit.nl/static/nl/gratiscursus/photoshop/8/ph_07.jpg
https://www.volkswagen.nl/~/media/Volkswagen/Images/Modellen/nieuwe%20up/up-hero-menu2.ashx?bc=White&as=0&h=310&w=860
http://www.volkswagen.nl/~/media/Volkswagen/Images/Modellen/nieuwe%20up/up-hero-menu2.ashx?bc=White&as=0&h=310&w=860

The code I use to show the WebView:

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><head> <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""adefault.css""> </head><body>" + c.HtmlSource + "</body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseURL>().Get();
browser.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
browser.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
browser.WidthRequest = 100;
browser.HeightRequest = 1000;
```

The `c.HtmlSource` in this case is the code containing the `<p>` showed at this start of the question.

Can somebody tell me why this specific image is not loading in the Xamarin.Forms WebView on the Android and iOS platform?

The code of the class that implements IBaseURL on iOS:

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (BaseUrl_iOS))]
namespace LOI.iOS
{
    public class BaseUrl_iOS : IBaseURL
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        }
    }
}
```

The code of the class that implements IBaseURL on Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace LOI.Droid
{

    public class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseURL
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "file:///android_asset/";
        }
    }
}
```

The `IBaseURL` interface:

```
 public interface IBaseURL
 {
     string Get();
 }
```

Comment: It might help to see the implementation of `DependencyService.Get<IBaseURL>().Get();`

Comment: Weird, I just tested your code and at first I found the same thing as you on iOS. Http sources won't work by default  on iOS due to ATS (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/) but once I allowed http loads by setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in the iOS info.plist (which should not have affected the offending image since it was an https url) all of a sudden the image started appearing. And removing the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key caused the image to not display again. Very odd. On Android I could not reproduce the issue at all, the image always showed

Comment: Note I did not set htmlSource.BaseUrl in my test, it did not seem necessary for this test, but there still may be an issue in your platform specific implementation that _may_ affect this issue.